# Facebook ShareDialog doesn't load after a WebView open

Tags: android, facebook, android-webview, facebook-android-sdk, fbsdksharedialog

I am working on an android app which have local HTML pages to show in `WebView` and an option to share some content on `Facebook` using `ShareDialog`.

- When `ShareDialog` is shown after a `WebView` loading started, It keeps loading and nothing happens. Even if I close `WebView` and show `ShareDialog` it keeps loading.
- When `ShareDialog` is shown before `WebView` loading started, It works right.

I have try clearing `WebView` cache before showing `ShareDialog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling `webView.pauseTimers()` from `onPause()` of my Fragment, which is stopping all `WebView` process, resulting in above error.

Fixed it by `webView.resumeTimer()`  before showing dialog.